# Changing the value of a variable in another a class using a UIButton Swift 2

Tags: swift, class, swift2

I have a View Controller (called BackgroundViewController) which has a few buttons, each of them set the color of the background of a different view, my main view. (just called ViewController, yes I started this project about a month ago, before I knew that I should name it something better). For that I set a class, SoundboardBrain, which I intend to use to hold a lot of the app's logic. Here's the class so far:

```
var backgroundName = String()
init(){
backgroundName = "Image"}

func changeBackgroundName(background: String){
backgroundName = background}
```

Now, BackgroundViewController is kind of like a settings pane, where the user could select one of the options and a bullet point appears by the one that he checked. Here's one of the of the buttons:

```
@IBAction func whiteButton(sender: AnyObject){
    whiteBullet.hidden = false
    imageBullet.hidden = true
}
```

//Here I call the changeBackground function I defined in SoundboardBrain
       `SoundboardBrain.changeBackgroundName("White")`
//I then print the result of that and I still get "Image" NO MATTER WHAT!

So all I want to know is how to change a variable initialized in a class with a UIButton or another object of a ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the instance of SoundBrain somewhere in variable, or use a singleton. You could be initializing a new SoundBrain instance later.

Singleton is better for main app logic. Example:

```
class SoundboardBrain {
    static let shared = SoundboardBrain()

    var backgroundName = "Image"

    func changeBackgroundName(background: String) {
        backgroundName = background
    }

}

SoundboardBrain.shared.backgroundName
// now the property is "Image"

// in UIButton
SoundboardBrain.shared.changeBackgroundName("something")

SoundboardBrain.shared.backgroundName
// now it's "something"
```

Example was made in Playground, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't quite understand

Comment: @RedEagle2000 Edited my example.

Comment: For whatever reason, when I try to load any view or press any button associated with this code the app freezes up, but without any error messages in the console. I know this because when I commented them out, everything worked fine. I'm using Swift 2 and Xcode 7 Beta, so maybe it's just a glitch in that.